# Pattern matcher for two similar text having some dynamic text in between

Tags: java

How to create a single Pattern which will match with both the below text. The middle part is dynamic.

1. GET /xx/1234:abc232/yy/
2. GET /xx/4321:xyz555/yy/

Pattern.compile("GET /xx/*/yy/"); // not working..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` means 0-n occurences of the previous character/group. And your previous character is `/`. So your pattern would match strings like `GET /xx//yy/` or `GET /xx////////////yy/`.

You need to add `.` which matches any character:

```
Pattern.compile("GET /xx/.*/yy/");
```

Answer (score 0):

While a solution for pattern-matching already has been provided, I think that checking

```
text.startsWith("GET /xx/") && text.endsWith("/yy/")
```

is much simpler.